# .toLocaleString("sv", { minute: "2-digit"}); //only returns 1 digit when the minute is between 0-9

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get my program to write out the current time with two digits, both for hours and minutes, using this code but the minutes comes out as only 1 digit if the minute is between 0-9.

The code I'm using looks like this:

```
let dateAndTime = new Date();
let hour = dateAndTime.toLocaleString("sv", { hour: "2-digit" });
let minutes = dateAndTime.toLocaleString("sv", { minute: "2-digit"});
```

Why is the code above working only for the hours and not the minutes when it looks the same? I'm new to javascript so if there's another way to solve it as well I appreciate all the help.